# jQuery display nested ul on click of div in parent li

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

I am trying to get a hidden nested ul to display when a div in its parent li is clicked, and am having a heck of a time with it. As is, the initial hiding of the nested ul's works, and the div background image toggles just fine, but nothing else is working. Any suggestions?

Current code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="browseFields">
    <ul id="branches">
    <li><div class="buttonShow"></div><a href="#">1</a>
        <ul class="subField">
            <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
            <li><div class="buttonShow"></div> 
                <ul class="subField">
                    <li><a href="#">i</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ii</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">iii</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#">c</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><div class="buttonShow"></div><a href="#">3</a>
        <ul class="subField">
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Relavent CSS:

```
.buttonShow {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("../assets/images/plus.png") no-repeat scroll top left;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px; }

.buttonHide {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("../assets/images/minus.png") no-repeat scroll top left;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.subField').hide();
    $('.buttonShow').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonHide');
        $(this).parent().next('.subField').show('slow');
    });
    $('.buttonHide').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.subField').hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You toggle the class `buttonHide`, but the button still has the class `buttonShow` right? So you'll end up with a button that has both classes, and I think you need to be checking for that possibility before you do any actions in your event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.subField').hide();
    //use event delegation since classes are changed dynamically
    $('#branches').on('click', '.buttonShow', function () {
        //remove the show class and assign hidden
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonHide buttonShow');
        //the subfield is a child of the parent not the next sibling
        $(this).siblings('.subField').show('slow');
    });
    $('#branches').on('click', '.buttonHide', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonHide buttonShow');
        $(this).siblings('.subField').hide('slow');

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5eB4F/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help. Also thanks for the notes, helped clarify a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.subField').hide();

    $('.browseFields').on("click" , ".buttonShow" , function() {
        $(this).removeClass('buttonShow').addClass("buttonHide");
        $(this).parent().find('.subField').show('slow');
    });
    $('.browseFields').on("click" , ".buttonHide" , function() {
        $(this).removeClass('buttonHide').addClass("buttonShow");
        $(this).parent().find('.subField').hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try merging the click handlers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.subField').hide();
    //use event delegation since classes are changed dynamically
    $('#branches').on('click', '.buttonShow, .buttonHide', function () {
        $(this).hasClass('buttonShow') ? $(this).siblings('.subField').show('slow') : $(this).siblings('.subField').hide('slow');

        $(this).toggleClass('buttonHide buttonShow');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working fiddle at here. Please check
http://jsfiddle.net/rwb75/9/

I have made some changes in your jQuery. Also i have made some changes in your html.
I have put `<div class="buttonShow"><a href="#">1</a></div>` anchor tag in div.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.subField').hide();
        $(document).on("click",".buttonShow",function(e) {
            $(this).addClass('buttonHide');
            $(this).removeClass('buttonShow');
           $(this).closest('li').find('.subField').eq(0).show('slow');        
        });
         $(document).on("click",".buttonHide",function(e) {
            debugger
             $(this).addClass('buttonShow');
             $(this).removeClass('buttonHide');
             $(this).closest('li').find('.subField').eq(0).hide('slow');
        });
    });
```